# On Debian system, keepalived is consuming full cpu usage on both kibana nodes

Tags: high-availability, elasticsearch, keepalived, kibana, keep-alive

I have master/slave kibana machines on Debian 10. From few days, cpu usage of keepalived daemon on both nodes are reaching to 100%. After keepalived restart it goes to normal, and this loops forever.

I am not sure, what exactly is wrong with my keepalived configuration. Can you please guide me here?

```
root@kib-e01:/var/log# keepalived -v
Keepalived v2.0.10 (11/12,2018)
root@kib-e01:/var/log# uname -r
4.19.0-13-amd64
root@kib-e01:/var/log#

root@kib-e02:/var/log# keepalived -v
Keepalived v2.0.10 (11/12,2018)
root@kib-e02:/var/log# uname -r
4.19.0-17-amd64
root@kib-e02:/var/log#
```

syslog-

```
Jan 21 08:16:38 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Jan 21 08:16:38 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Jan 21 08:16:38 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Jan 21 08:16:38 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Jan 21 08:16:39 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: VRRP_Script(check_script) succeeded
Jan 21 08:16:39 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: (ha-kibana-s) Entering BACKUP STATE
Jan 21 08:16:42 kibana-s02 kib-e01[35862]: (ha-kibana-s) Entering MASTER STATE
```

My /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf from **MASTER Keepalive**

```
vrrp_script check_script {
        script "/usr/bin/curl --noproxy "127.0.0.1" -s -k https://127.0.0.1:443/status"
        interval 2
        fall 2
        rise 2
}

global_defs {
    notification_email {
        admin@xyz.com
    }
    notification_email_from kib-e01
    smtp_server localhost
    smtp_connect_timeout 30
    enable_script_security
}

vrrp_instance ha-kibana-s {
        interface eth0
        state MASTER
        priority 200
  advert_int 1
        virtual_router_id 33
        unicast_src_ip 10.14.150.34

        unicast_peer {
                10.14.150.35
        }

        track_script {
                check_script
        }

authentication {
                auth_type PASS
                # Only the first eight (8) characters are used.
                auth_pass fderty6y
}

        virtual_ipaddress {
                10.14.150.33 brd 10.14.150.255 dev eth0 label vip
        }

}
```

ip a of master machine:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b2:67:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.14.150.34/24 brd 10.14.150.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.14.150.33/32 brd 10.14.150.255 scope global vip
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb2:678b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```